# EFI: Grub menu doesn't display

Tags: centos, grub2, uefi

I ave a computer with CentOS 7 installed that boots up using EFI and grub2 (I'm not exactly sure what the difference between UEFI and EFI is).  If it makes a difference the partition table is GPT.

The machine boots properly and works fine.  However, on startup the grub menu doesn't display correctly.  I can't see any of the options and the count down timer "Selected option will boot in 5 4 3" or whatever it says is wrapped (so the start of the sentence is on the right and the end wraps around to the left).

The grub config selects "console" as the terminal output method.  I'm not really sure what I'm meant to try changing in order to fix this?  How do I go about solving it?

p.s. I haven't made any changes to the default CentOS set up with regards to booting, but there were some options to choose (e.g. I think they allow pure UEFI boot without grub).

Comment: UEFI is successor to EFI as Akito correctly noted; GPT is "related" in a sense that MSFT chose to couple UEFI/GPT, BIOS/MBR for some reason (I can understand a part of it but don't know for sure) so many firmware manufacturers will assume that's the only combos they have to test.

Comment: Regarding GRUB, what exactly do you see instead of its menu?  "console" means textmode console, not a graphical menu; looks like this doesn't work with UEFI GOP correctly in your case, *maybe* switching to e.g. "gfxboot" with some `GRUB_GFXMODE='800x600'` nearby and a `grub-mkconfig` as GRUB2 [expects](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Invoking-grub_002dmkconfig.html) would help.
If CentOS isn't a given, you might also try e.g. Debian, openSUSE or, well, [ALT](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) (I've implemented UEFI support there :).

Comment: For general (U)EFI introduction, and a pretty good and readable one, I'd warmly recommend [Rod's books](http://rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) on this topic, helped me a lot back then.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin: CentOS is a given.  I have a blank screen except for the wrongly aligned display counting down when my "selection" will be chosen.

Comment: try switching GRUB to gfxboot then.

Answer (score 1):

As a general thumb rule: **do not use (U)EFI if you don't know what you're doing.**

**Introduction**
Many new mainboards start using *UEFI* as a default way for the *BIOS* to boot systems etc. And that's fine for a generic user, who has Windows 10 pre-installed on his Alienware machine. But if the user starts customizing his machine especially regarding the addition of other OSes even more so with Unix based operating systems then stuff gets tricky due to the slow overall standardization of **U**nified **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface.

**UEFI vs. EFI**
First of all, there is no important difference between *UEFI* and *EFI* except that *UEFI* is basically the successor to *EFI*. Some people could probably call it *EFI2.0*. *UEFI* has more functions, but is limited to booting only compatible systems with compatible setups whereas for example the customized *EFI* made by *Apple Inc.* supports more of these. But that's not really important in your case.

**Explanation for the cause of your problem**
**UEFI** is a great thing, that's why I use it myself. It has many good traits and is definitely superior to the *Legacy MBR* system. Sadly many system nowadays, especially those which don't get fed by capitalistic money sucking, like for example open source OSes, still rely mostly on being used on the old Legacy *MBR* system. More and more of these distributions, especially the more known ones like Ubuntu for example, become compatible with *UEFI* but they aren't exactly *perfectly prepared* for it. Sometimes installation doesn't go smoothly or doesn't work at all. And sometimes people don't exactly know what the differences between *UEFI* and *BIOS/MBR* based installations are, so something gets wrongly chosen/configured and then the boot doesn't work properly as in your case.

**Summary of what you have to do**
What usually counts is the general rule of thumb above in this answer. But since you say that your *HDD* is *GPT* formatted and your *BIOS* obviously supports *(U)EFI* then the only other thing that you should make sure is that you **install your OS in (U)EFI mode**. Get the newest *Rufus* for Windows, plug in an empty USB flash drive, select it in *Rufus*, **select Partition as GPT for UEFI** (which is the third formatting option). **Make sure the USB flash drive is formatted in FAT32.** Now choose the CentOS.iso, click start.
After it finishes, restart your computer and select **((U)EFI) CentOS Flash Drive** in your BIOS. You literally have to select the (U)EFI option, so it gets installed in this mode. Else your problem will probably persist. Then proceed as usual with your installation. If you selected everything right, you can even check if the system selected or even made an *EFI* partition, which would definitely mean all goes well.

Comment: CentOS is installed in UEFI mode.  I have an EFI partition that is used for booting.  It works.  Only grub has display problems and I'm not sure why (it might not even be UEFI related!).

Comment: Did you try to purge and re-install GRUB2? If you want to try it the easy way, you can boot into boot-repair disk. It will basically reset your GRUB2. Maybe it helps?